# Apache2 rewriting without rules

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

So i've a Wordpress site on my domain and i want to add subdomains with their own php code. I'm using mod_rewrite for wordpress and want to use it for my own projects but weirdly i can access urls that should result in a 404 error. For example i can access test/somestuff/morestuff and get test.php (without any $_GET set). But i have no .htaccess file in the directories for the virtual hosts. I then tried to delete the .htaccess from wordpress, restart apache2, and try again but i get the same behavior on the virtual host and wordpress doesn't work with permalinks (like i thought it would). My sites-available configs don't have any rewrite rules in them. Why can i access URLs that shouldn't work? Am i missing some feature of apache?

Answer (score 0):

So after some more trying i've discovered the error was that i've had MultiViews enabled for the virtual host. I've disabled it and now it works.